# Do i need multiple streams and TCP clients to make a chat application in c#

Tags: c#, sockets, networking, network-programming, tcpclient

i am using the following code on server for communication between the server and client

```
TcpListener server = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 9999);
server.Start();

Console.WriteLine("Waiting for client connections");
TcpClient client = server.AcceptTcpClient();
Console.WriteLine("Client request accepted");

NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
```

Now this code works fine for connecting a single client, But what tweaking i need to do in order allow more than one client to connect to my server ?

Do i need a new TCP listener on a new port for each client ? Do i need Multiple TCP clients and streams ? A brief guide on making this code be able to handle >1 clients would be appreciated.

Comment: Yes, you would need to handle multiple connections to handle multiple clients.  Unless you resolve a very serious problem ( the fact your server code will accept a single client then disconnect ) you will have a huge challenge modifying your existing oode.

Comment: In short, you only need one listener, but multiple streams. Each time a client connects, you accept the connection. You'll want to have a client class to handle all of this. Rather than going into detail and posting an answer, I will suggest you look for some sample code (it's abundant).

Comment: There are two ways, you either need to use asynchronous sockets, or you need to create a new thread for each TcpClient that you accept, start an infinite loop in the new thread(s), and wait and listen. Using the thread technique doesn't scale well at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would still have one listener ... but each "accept" should spawn a different thread or task.  The new thread would then create it's own stream.

Answer (score 2):

You would want to put the `server.AcceptTcpClient()` in a loop as each time a new client connects it will return another `TcpClient`.  You can see a simple example of this in the MSDN documentation [here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.accepttcpclient.aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.accepttcpclient.aspx)

Comment: I would instead recommend creating a new thread for each new connection.  The MSDN link is a good example, but it can only handle one client at a time.  IMHO...

Comment: @paulsm4 I would agree, you probably don't want to have it all running on a single thread, but I didn't want to get into to much hairy detail.

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this on server side:

```
            while (true)
            {
              if (server.Pending()) // if there are any pending connections to server
                  {
                      //accept tcpClient and perform further operations.
                      //create a different thread per client
                   }
            }
```